# Using conda environment in IPython interactive shell

Tags: ipython, anaconda, environment, conda

I am trying to use the interactive shell of IPython within my conda env and am having issues.
The steps I take are:

```
source activate myenv
conda install ipython
ipython
```

When I am in ipython interactive shell, it calls python from the anaconda root bin. (`~/anaconda2/bin'`)

Is there anything I can do to change the python path to `~/anaconda2/envs/myenv/bin` and import packages from myenv?

I see few solutions to making env work in jupyter when I search the web, but no answer on making it work on the interactive shell.

Comment: What does `which ipython` return when you are in your myenv (i.e. after running `source activate myenv`)?

Comment: it returns `~/anaconda2/envs/work/bin/ipython`

Comment: I don't know why, but for some reason it works now!

Comment: If you restarted your shell, sometimes that fixes issues with cached locations of executables.

Comment: @darthbith that solved it for me.  After that `ipython` uses same python as `which python`

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to your `$PATH` variable being messed up.

THe easiest way to make sure you get IPython from within an env is to use `$ python -m IPython <rest of the options>` to start IPython. This works for many of the Python installable application; like pytest, pip and other.