# Installing Tensorflow for Python 3.6.0

Tags: tensorflow

can somebody explain to me what to do step by step for installation of Tensorflow for Python 3.7.0! (I'm using ipython)!
My system is windows 10 64 bit system.
I do not understand what to do even with all the explanation I find so far.
So can somebody pointed me to the exact link I have to click on to install tensor flow? Tnx

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

~\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: DLL load failed: Een initialisatieroutine van de dynamic link library (DLL-bestand) is mislukt.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fae406f752e9> in <module>()
      6 from PIL import Image
      7 from scipy import ndimage
----> 8 import tensorflow as tf
      9 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
     10 from cnn_utils import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>()
     20 
     21 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 22 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     23 
     24 try:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Een initialisatieroutine van de dynamic link library (DLL-bestand) is mislukt.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Comment: Hi,

via my anaconda prompt I used 2 following commands C:> conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5 
C:> activate tensorflow

But when using in ipython following command

import tensorflow as tf
and run the cell I still have following error:
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
Can somebody help me with what I should do or what I do wrong?

Comment: tensorflow cpu or gpu?

Comment: CPU (it is on my laptop)!

Comment: my first guess would be you're facing the same error as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682872/using-conda-environment-in-ipython-interactive-shell). Have you tried closing and restarting the shell?

Comment: also, check the c++ runtime as mentioned in the [doc page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). Make sure to have the exact same thing installed.

Comment: if everything above is done and still doesn't work, then it might be a problem with anaconda, try
1. Upgrade setuptools:
`pip install --upgrade -I setuptools`

2. Install TensorFlow again with `--ignore-installed` flag in your `pip install` command.

Comment: and just in case..`conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5` this line of command doesn't install tensorflow, it just creates a seperate conda environment with the name _tensorflow_.

Comment: @JialerChew what should I execute after the command conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6 ? I don't know if I have closed and restarting the shell. It's all so confusing for me. As said I have python 3.6.3 installed on my laptop. I writing code via ipython but I'm not enable to executed the command import tensorflow as tf. So all I do is opening a command prompt from anaconda and then fill in following command: conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6 and as follow activate tensorflow ... But for one reason or another it is not working. Or can you tell me how to install with PIP, which cmnd promt

Comment: I understand now seems like your problem is you have not even installed tensorflow..I'm assuming you already have pip in your computer?

Comment: yes, I have pip, at least I remember I used one time already the pip command but remember not anymore where or how to use the pip command. Which command prompt, which command with pip?

Comment: look at the answer I suggested below..it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing installation steps from the [official tensorflow installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) specifically for your case.

Since you already have Python 3.6 and Conda installed on your machine (which is good!) we can move on to confirming the other stuffs.

### 1. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3

Install the *Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3*. This comes with *Visual Studio 2015* but can be installed separately:

1. Go to the [Visual Studio downloads](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/),
2. Select *Redistributables and Build Tools*, (it is well hidden, use search to look for it)
3. Download and install the *Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3*.

[image: Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3]

### 2. Install Tensorflow in your Conda virtual environment

Open your Command Prompt. Since you already have the environment created with the name `tensorflow` you just need to:

1. In case you wish to create a new environment, run `conda create -n venv pip python=3.6`. Replace `venv` with a name of your choice for the environment.
2. `source activate tensorflow`. `tensorflow` in this line is the name of the Conda environment you named when you ran `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6`. Unless you've followed step 1 and made a new environment, replace `tensorflow` with the name you used in step 1.
3. Now you have activated your virtual environment. Within the virtual environment, install the Tensorflow pip package using its [complete URL](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#package-location), so for your case, just run:

`pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Please update the URL in the command above according to the URL list if you're installing this again in the future. The command above will become outdated eventually.

### 3. Verifying the install

Restart your Command Prompt, and again activate your conda environment, then run `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"`, and it should print the version of Tensorflow you have installed, in this case 1.11.0. If it does, then you have successfully installed Tensorflow in your Conda virtual environment. Congratulations!

If it doesn't work, comment here so I can modify my answer to further assist you.

Comment: I have a stack trace error when import tensorflow now. I did all the above steps you recommended. As I have not enough characters left to put my stactrace here in the comment, I will put it as an answer ok? So please look at the answer I posted. Tnx

Comment: @Ilse can you confirm the python version you are using for the conda environment you would install tensorflow in? after you activated your environment type run `python3 --version` to confirm your version. Just to confirm it's not due to versioning since you've mentioned 3 different Python versions throughout this question...

Comment: @Ilse for debugging purposes, make sure you are using version 3.6.x for this installation. thanks.

Comment: after you have confirmed that you are indeed using Python 3.6.x, my final suggestion would be to use an earlier version of tensorflow instead of 1.11.0, you can install an earlier version by changing the URL you used in your pip install. Example to install 1.10.0 you change the URL to `https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.10.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: @Ilse since I have solved your `ModuleNotFoundError` it would be great if you could accept my answer first, then open your new error as a separate question, then I will continue assisting you from there on. Thank you.

Comment: I have version 3.6.x installed. So I will try the other link you sugested. OK where do I accept your answer? I will search anyway where to find it... Sure will I accept your answer. Already great thanks for the help provided so far...

Comment: you should be able to click on a green tick directly on the left of my answer, refer to this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png)

Comment: Done, as said I will tried the link for earlier version of tensorflow. I'll keep you in touch. tnx

Comment: @Ilse if it's possible please format your new question nicely, it's quite difficult to read as it is now..and also specify which version you are using..and did the error appear when running the test command I've suggested, which is `python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"`?

Comment: I formatted the new question as code. How do you want me to format it, can you format it in a way readable for you? Yes I received the error after executing python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"?

Comment: @Ilse oh sorry I thought you were referring to your question at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659074/installing-tensorflow-for-latest-python-3-release-python-3-6-0-follow-up). May I know which tensorflow version you are using now? You installed the Microsoft Visual C++ also right?

Comment: Yes it was at the link you preferred too. I noticed it was not formatted as code. I did it now. But now the stacktrace appears as one line. Hopefully it can help you further. Yes I installed Microsoft Visual C++ and my current version of tensor flow I installed is now 1.10.0 (Previous it was 1.11.0). Will it possible also as from now to answer on my new request, because here it becomes a real mess...

Comment: Hello Jialer, sorry to bodder you again but do you have not any idea anymore what could be possible wrong? tnx

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow does not support Python 3.7 yet (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022).

Use Python 3.6.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... it is python 3.6 installed on my system but anyway same problem!

Comment: The this is a different question. Please create a new question (and also it would be nice to accept mine. ;).

Comment: For your info, Python 3.7 [works now](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17022). Please do not just spam the general answer, instead try to understand the real problem. Cheers.

Comment: @JialerChew: Your link (which is my link) and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/20517#issuecomment-423268071 confirm that Python 3.7 is not supported. So you are not answering the question of the OP.

Comment: you attempted to solve the `ModuleNotFoundError` by suggesting a different python version? are you sure you are breaking down OP's problem to its root cause and trying to solve one by one?

Comment: @Andreas Pasternak few days you posted IIse, please clean up your question. – Andreas Pasternak Is there still something to clean up? In case yes, what exactly? In meanwhile I posted new question as follow up... on request of Jialer Chew.