# Installing Tensorflow for Latest Python 3 Release - Python 3.6.0 (follow up)

Tags: tensorflow

On request of @Jialer Chew new question posted as follow up from 
Installing Tensorflow for Latest Python 3 Release - Python 3.6.0!
Previous question rases out of border.
My problem installing Tensorflow is now as follow:

`--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper() 13 try: ---> 14 return importlib.import_module(mname) 15 except ImportError: ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package) 125 level += 1 --> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 127 ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _gcd_import(name, package, level) ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_) ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_) ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _load_unlocked(spec) ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in module_from_spec(spec) ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap_external.py in create_module(self, spec) ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds) ImportError: DLL load failed: Een initialisatieroutine van de dynamic link library (DLL-bestand) is mislukt. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>() 57 ---> 58 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * 59 from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__ ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>() 16 return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') ---> 17 _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() 18 del swig_import_helper ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper() 15 except ImportError: ---> 16 return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') 17 _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() ~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module(name, package) 125 level += 1 --> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 127 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: ImportError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-fae406f752e9> in <module>() 6 from PIL import Image 7 from scipy import ndimage ----> 8 import tensorflow as tf 9 from tensorflow.python.framework import ops 10 from cnn_utils import * ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>() 20 21 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order ---> 22 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow # pylint: disable=unused-import 23 24 try: ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>() 47 import numpy as np 48 ---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow 50 51 # Protocol buffers ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>() 72 for some common reasons and solutions. Include the entire stack trace 73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc() ---> 74 raise ImportError(msg) 75 76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module(mname) File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed: Een initialisatieroutine van de dynamic link library (DLL-bestand) is mislukt. During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module> from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import * File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in <module> _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper() File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal') File "C:\Users\gstevens\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal' Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime. See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems`

Comment: hi sorry for the late reply. Seems like I'm kind of out of idea here. The only thing I can think of is trying out older versions than 1.10.0..if it still doesnt work then I would try uninstalling it then reinstall again.

Comment: Seems like the most popular methods now is uninstalling tensorflow and trying out with an older version. you can try uninstalling with `pip uninstall tensorflow` and then reinstalling using the method I mentioned in your previous question.

Comment: there's people reinstalling all the way up to version 1.6 and even 1.3, so please do not hesitate to try downgrading it.

Comment: @Jialer Chew sorry for my reply so late but just now found the time to try installing tensor flow with older version. I succeeded with version 1.2.0 finally :-) Will update from time to time to see till which version it will go. Thank you so much for your effort you put in this thread...